# Кавычки и тире при прямой речи, беспрестанно перебиваемой авторской

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, редактура

> Я протянула ему телефон, и он принялся медленно, откровенно нехотя,
>   одним пальцем вводить цифры в систему. Нажал «сенд» – и посмотрел на
>   меня. «Вы знаете, что сегодня четверг? –  неожиданно заявил он. –
>   Завтра пятница», – он поднял глаза на меня. Затем начал загибать
>   пальцы и сильно растягивать английские слова: «Сууббооотааа…
>   Вооооскрееееесенье…» – Он уставился на свою руку и добавил упомянутые
>   вначале четверг и пятницу, загнув поочередно два пальца. Потряс куцей
>   культёй. «Все на море, мадам! – воскликнул он. – Все на море!» Он
>   прочёл что-то на экране рабочего компьютера, вздохнул и просто его
>   выключил. «Вы лучше приходите в понедельник. Мы ведь уже закрываемся».
>   И он, чуть обхватив, подтолкнул меня к порогу, а сам пошёл к окнам –
>   опускать жалюзи… Как потом выяснилось, всё, что ему нужно было
>   сделать, принять к оплате счёт. Положить деньги в кассу. Но иногда
>   ведь бывает просто лень, а бывает, и на море очень надо…

Что-то не то у меня с закрыть/открыть кавычки и тире между ними...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кавычки на месте, а вот тире можно поубавить, чуть изменив границы предложений.

Нажал «сенд» – и посмотрел на меня. «Вы знаете, что сегодня четверг? – неожиданно заявил он. – Завтра пятниц**а». Он поднял глаза на меня, затем  начал загибать пальцы и сильно растягивать английские слова:** «Сууббооотааа… Вооооскрееееесенье…» **(нет тире, предложение с прямой речью окончилось)** Он уставился на свою руку и добавил упомянутые вначале четверг и пятницу, загнув поочередно два пальца. Потряс куцей культёй. «Все на море, мадам! – воскликнул он. – Все на море!» Он прочёл что-то на экране рабочего компьютера, вздохнул и просто его выключил. «Вы лучше приходите в понедельник. Мы ведь уже закрываемся». И он, чуть обхватив, подтолкнул меня к порогу, а сам пошёл к окнам – опускать жалюзи… Как потом выяснилось, всё, что ему нужно было сделать, **- это**  принять к оплате счёт. Положить деньги в кассу. Но иногда ведь бывает просто лень, а бывает, и на море очень надо…

Answer (score 2):

Розенталь: § 53. **Абзацы при прямой речи**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161#pp161

Но если в тексте от автора описывается **действие** говорящего лица, то и авторский текст, и последующая прямая речь **выделяются в абзацы.**

Я протянула ему телефон, и он принялся медленно, откровенно нехотя, одним пальцем вводить цифры в систему. Нажал «сенд» – и посмотрел на меня.

– Вы знаете, что сегодня четверг? – неожиданно заявил он. – Завтра пятница.

Он поднял глаза на меня. Затем начал загибать пальцы и сильно растягивать английские слова: «Сууббооотааа… Вооооскрееееесенье…»

Он уставился на свою руку и добавил упомянутые вначале четверг и пятницу, загнув поочередно два пальца. Потряс куцей культёй.

– Все на море, мадам! – воскликнул он. – Все на море!

Он прочёл что-то на экране рабочего компьютера, вздохнул и просто его выключил.

– Вы лучше приходите в понедельник. Мы ведь уже закрываемся.

И он, чуть обхватив, подтолкнул меня к порогу, а сам пошёл к окнам – опускать жалюзи… Как потом выяснилось, всё, что ему нужно было сделать, принять к оплате счёт. Положить деньги в кассу. Но иногда ведь бывает просто лень, а бывает, и на море очень надо

Comment: Жасминушка, спасибо, но этот совет не для меня: в тексте свои смысловые абзацы; здесь - отдельный эпизод, который только и может быть что внакрут.

Comment: Возможно, правило Розенталя не всегда применяется. А ничего, что местоимение "он" часто повторяется?

Answer (score 0):

Не берусь расставлять кавычки, но хочу заметить, что "система" звучит внушительно, даже пугающе, а цифры обычно вводят не в "систему", а в некое поле на экране. Если нужно изобразить человека, для которого мир компьтеров - непонятная страшная СИСТЕМА, то цель достигнута. А в нейтральном изложении цифры просто нажимают (набирают) на клавиатуре.